# Show Real time value from mysql to andrroid recyclery view

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch data from mysql using php in recycler view with volley. Is there any method to auto update recycler view as soon as new data get inserted in table like real time chat application?

Adapter Class

```
package com.vipulashishsanket.vadakvadan.Adapter;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.vipulashishsanket.vadakvadan.R;
import com.vipulashishsanket.vadakvadan.SharedPrefManager;
import com.vipulashishsanket.vadakvadan.fetchingClass.Chat;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    public static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT=0;
    public static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT=1;
    private Context mcontext;
    private List<Chat> mchat;
    private String imgurl;


    public MessageAdapter(Context mcontext, List<Chat> mchat )
    {
        this.mchat=mchat;
        this.mcontext=mcontext;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType==MSG_TYPE_RIGHT){
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.chat_bubble_right,parent,false);
            return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }
        else
        {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.chat_bubble_left,parent,false);
            return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chat chat=mchat.get(position);
        holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mchat.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView show_message;

        public ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);

            show_message=view.findViewById(R.id.msg);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        String userid= SharedPrefManager.getInstance(mcontext).getUid();
        if(mchat.get(position).getSender().equals(userid))
        {
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        }
        else
        {
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }
    }


}
```

This is my adapter call where i fetch the messages from mysql database

```
package com.vipulashishsanket.vadakvadan;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.vipulashishsanket.vadakvadan.Adapter.MessageAdapter;
import com.vipulashishsanket.vadakvadan.fetchingClass.Chat;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class InboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Chat> chatList;
    MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    String url="http://192.168.1.210/Vadak_Vajan_DB/v1/loadmessage.php";
    Intent intent;
    String murl="http://192.168.1.210/Vadak_Vajan_DB/v1/sendMessage.php";
    String userid;
    EditText message;
    CircleImageView send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.msg_recycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        chatList=new ArrayList<>();
        messageAdapter=new MessageAdapter(getApplicationContext(),chatList);
        message=findViewById(R.id.insert_msg);
        send=findViewById(R.id.send_msg);
//        recyclerView.notify();

        intent=getIntent();
        userid=intent.getStringExtra("uid");

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendmessage();
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });


        loadMsg();
    }

    private void loadMsg()
    {
        StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("message");
                            for(int j=0;j<jsonArray.length();j++)
                            {
                                JSONObject o=jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                Chat mchat=new Chat(
                                        o.getString("sender_id"),
                                        o.getString("receiver_id"),
                                        o.getString("message")
                                );

                                chatList.add(mchat);

                            }


                            messageAdapter =new MessageAdapter(getApplication(), chatList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                String uid=SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUid();

                Map<String ,String> map=new HashMap<>();
                map.put("sender_id",uid);
                map.put("receiver_id",userid);

                return map;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    public void sendmessage()
    {
        StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                murl,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);

                            messageAdapter =new MessageAdapter(getApplication(), chatList);
                            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                String uid=SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getUid();
                Map<String ,String> map=new HashMap<>();
                map.put("sender_id",uid);
                map.put("receiver_id",userid);
                map.put("message",message.getText().toString().trim());


                return map;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }
}
```

In activity i am having loadmessage api and send message api after send i want to automatically update the list i used notifydatachange but itis not working properly

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any `realtime` feature in `sql` database . There are some database available which provide `realtime` feature for example `Firebase`.In firebase `onDatachanged` method call whenever table data change.Try to use firebase for chat module.